Cannot redeclare GuzzleHttp\describe_type() Error
Hey i am facing an issue

An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 41 of the file /home/customer/www/wpaipros.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ssml-processor/awssdk/GuzzleHttp/functions.php. Error message: Cannot redeclare GuzzleHttp\describe_type() (previously declared in /home/customer/www/wpaipros.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/eroom-zoom-meetings-webinar-pro/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php:16)

SSML Plugin is made by our developers and the other one is being bought , we are trying to resolve the issue now i would appreciate for any related answers
I tried Using internet and AI tools too to solve this , some one told me to use some autoloader which i am not sure and some told to use different names of the functions

The error is pretty self-explanatory.  You have a duplicate name.  Solutions -

Don't use one of the libraries
Change the name of the function that your developers have written.  Surely it is not an issue if they have written it.

